# JSSOR - External links on thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

If I have this:

```
<div>
  <img u="image" src="../img/photography/002.jpg" />
  <div u="thumb">
    <img class="i" src="../img/photography/thumb-002.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
  <div u="caption" t="R"><a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that I will have an external link to http://mylink.com in the caption but I dont want that. I want an external link on the thumbnail. How do I acomplish that?
Am I wrong to think that I must add something to the `u=prototype` div?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code,

```
<div>
  <img u="image" src="../img/photography/002.jpg" />
  <div u="thumb">
    <a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank"><img class="i" src="../img/photography/thumb-002.jpg"/></a>
  </div>
  <div u="caption" t="L">My Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```